# Non differentiable function satisfying Lipschitz condition

Tags: real-analysis

Consider functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with the property that |f(x)-f(y)|$\le $4321|x-y| for all real numbers x,y. Then prove that there exists at least one such f that is continuous, but is non differentiable at exactly 2018 points and satisfying  $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{|x|}$=2018

I can get a continuous non differentiable function say f(x)=4321|x|. Please help me to get a function which is non differentiable at exactly 2018 points. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How about $f(x)=|x|+|x-1|+..+|x-2018|$ ?

Comment: Thank you. But how about the limit it must satisfy?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac {f(x)}{|x|}=\lim_{x \to +\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{2018} \big| 1-\frac i{x} \big|=\sum_{i=1}^{2018}1=2018$

Comment: Sorry for another question. Does your function satisfy Lipschitz?

Comment: Of course it's Lipschitz but the constant gets doubled.

Comment: That is what troubling me! I beleive one should do it case by case like $x,y \gt 2018$ or $x,y \lt 0$ ..etc.

Comment: Will f(x)=1/2 {|x|+ |x-1|+......up to 2017} work?

Comment: I think f(x)= 1/2018 {|x|+|x-1|…up to 2017} is the correct choice for f(x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{2018} |x-i|$

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Now for any $1\le i \le 2018$

$|x-y|=|x-i-y+i| =|x-i-(y-i)| \ge |x-i|-|y-i| \quad (1)$

(since $|a-b| \ge ||a|-|b||$ )

Taking sum over $i$ in $(1)$

$2018 |x-y|\ge f(x)-f(y)$

$\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|\le 2018 |x-y| \le 4321|x-y|  $

Also the function is continous and non-differentiable at $x=1,2,3,..,2018$

Now $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{|x|}=\lim_{x\to +\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{2018} \big|1-\frac 1x\big|=2018$

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the answer.